# Turbo shaft broken

Tags: engine, ford, turbocharger

Ford Fiesta 1.4 diesel TDCI

There was a rattling noise. Checked and found that noise is due to damaged turbo turbine. So turbo replaced. But after replacement with new turbo and 10KMS road test, the noise returned. Checked and found the turbo turbine damaged from same side.

Comment: Did you ensure there was a good oil supply to the turbo bearings before you fitted the new one?

Comment: Yes oil pump is proper working.

Comment: I m going to proceed with compression test..may be it is due to low compression.

Comment: I doubt a compression test will help. did you physically connect an oil pressure gauge to the turbo oil lines? You need to take the turbo apart and inspect the points of failure to determine what you should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common problem is that gunk builds up in the oil feed pipes to the turbo which restricts the flow of oil to the turbo bearings. This then causes rapid failure of the new turbo. Some manufactures require that you replace the oil feed pipes when fitting a new turbo for this reason.

Comment: I just check its compression reading.    Its dry readings are   6    5   8   5      and wet are     9  11 7   8        it seems its engine is down....  because its oil pan is in hit  condition.....